# Is it possible to set SQLite DB on server and connect to it in an Android app?

Tags: sqlite, android

I'm creating an app as a study project. One of requirements is not to hardcode. For this reason, I want to get data from DB with every start of the app and change data stored in DB outside of the app code. I wanted to use Redis and store data in JSON at first, but there were too many problems, because Redis doesn't work with Android by default.

So, the question is: is it possible to use SQLite set on server? I know that this DB is not supposed to work in client-server mode, but I have found out some SQLite hostings in the Internet. If it is possible, how to perform it? If not, which way should I store data? SQL format is pretty convenient for me, because it is literally a table.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. SQLite is an [embedded database engine](https://sqlite.org/about.html), which means it runs as part of your program and uses a file (usually) in the [application sandbox](https://source.android.com/security/app-sandbox) on Android (so this is *not* part of your source code).

> SQLite is an embedded SQL database engine. Unlike most other SQL databases, SQLite does not have a separate server process. SQLite reads and writes directly to ordinary disk files.

It's probably possible to have an application run on a server which is able to function as a backend for your app and stores its data in a SQLite file, but I'd rather choose a database which is *intended* for this kind of purposes like PostgreSQL or MySQL. You can talk SQL to those databases too. Of course, in a production-grade application you'll need an *application* as a back end, not just a database, which is able to authenticate users, validate business logic etc.